# Is it possible to hide the HTML attributes generated by AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is it possible to hide the attributes generated by Angular, like `ng-app`, `ng-init` etc in the generated html? This is because I want to clean up the html that is visible to the user. In my app I am initializing `ng-init` with some data received from the server. This is causing the generated html to display the entire initialization data. The html does not look good.

Comment: Can't you use `$scope` in your controller to get the data from the server?

Comment: It's all **client-side** JavaScript, so it's visible to the prying eye no matter what you do. Btw, ng-init is actually a directive that should be used only for simple helper assignments, not for loading data from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the attributes within the elements in the source?

To make those valid you can:

add the angular namespace to your html: `<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app>`

change the directives to prefix with "data-" making them valid html5 data-* attributes
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive